# Slow query performance, for just a 'simple' Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple sql query which is performing not so well.
The dataset is also pretty straightforward, just a tasks table and a user_tasks table. 
In the DB are at the moment just 50.000 records present

I have indexes on the tasks fields and user_tasks fields.

The query is taking > 300ms to complete.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t0."id") *
FROM "tasks" t0  INNER JOIN
     "user_tasks" u1
     ON TRUE 
WHERE (t0."id" = u1."task_id") AND
      (((u1."user_id" = 'f4325fd5-8862-4563-a534-957d76ac98b9') AND t0."delegate_id" IS NULL) 
OR ((t0."delegate_id" = 'f4325fd5-8862-4563-a534-957d76ac98b9') AND   
       (u1."user_id" != 'f4325fd5-8862-4563-a534-957d76ac98b9'))) 
ORDER BY t0."id", t0."start_at"
```

here is the output of the explain analyse

```
Unique  (cost=75397.69..75398.18 rows=98 width=2979) (actual time=479.995..480.041 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=75397.69..75397.93 rows=98 width=2979) (actual time=479.994..480.004 rows=100 loops=1)
    Sort Key: t0.id, t0.start_at
      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 51kB
        ->  Gather  (cost=1000.85..75394.45 rows=98 width=2979) (actual time=17.529..479.734 rows=100 loops=1)
          Workers Planned: 2
            Workers Launched: 2
              ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.84..74384.65 rows=41 width=2979) (actual time=64.989..475.499 rows=33 loops=3)
                Merge Cond: (t0.id = u1.task_id)
                  Join Filter: (((u1.user_id = 'f4325fd5-8862-4563-a534-957d76ac98b9'::uuid) AND (t0.delegate_id IS NULL)) OR ((t0.delegate_id = 'f4325fd5-8862-4563-a534-957d76ac98b9'::uuid) AND (u1.user_id <> 'f4325fd5-8862-4563-a534-957d76ac98b9'::uuid)))
                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 123267
                      ->  Parallel Index Scan using tasks_id_index on tasks t0  (cost=0.42..44772.95 rows=154209 width=2919) (actual time=0.023..125.719 rows=123300 loops=3)
                        ->  Index Scan using user_tasks_task_id_index on user_tasks u1  (cost=0.42..25604.24 rows=369900 width=36) (actual time=0.042..253.000 rows=369755 loops=3)
Planning time: 0.506 ms
Execution time: 488.518 ms
```

I striped down the query until I noticed it becomes fast.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT DISTINCT ON (t0."id") * FROM "tasks" AS t0 
INNER JOIN "user_tasks" AS u1 ON (t0."id" = u1."task_id")
WHERE t0."delegate_id" = 'f4325fd5-8862-4563-a534-957d76ac98b9'  
OR  u1."user_id" = 'f4325fd5-8862-4563-a534-957d76ac98b9'
```

if I remove the OR and the statement it becomes fast ~0.7 ms, if I query on WHERE u1."user_id" = and its fast if I query on WHERE t0."delegate_id" = its fast

the task has a index on delegate_id 
user_tasks has index on user_id & task_id & user_task_id

Comment: I recommend running "EXPLAIN ANALYZE your_command" and adding the result to your question in order to show where the slowdown is occurring.

Comment: (1) `ON TRUE` ???.  (2) 300 ms does seem like a long time.

Comment: I use a orm, which is putting the ON TRUE there ..

Comment: On true plus join-condition in the where clause: maybe you should get yourself another ORM. And please (at least) add some DDL to the question. "I have indexes" is not sufficient to answer your question. `Rows Removed by Join Filter: 123267` says it all, IMHO

Comment: I fiddled around with the query and removed the on true and striped it down until I noticed it becomes fast.

Comment: `the task has a index on delegate_id user_tasks has index on user_id & task_id & user_task_id` That is not DDL. Most people here read DDL easier than sloppy texstual discriptions of it.

Answer (score 0):

nailed it

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
    SELECT * 
    FROM "tasks" AS t0 INNER JOIN
       (select *
        from user_tasks ut
        where user_id = 'f4325fd5-8862-4563-a534-957d76ac98b9'
       ) u1
        ON (t0."id" = u1."task_id")
     WHERE t0."delegate_id" = 'f4325fd5-8862-4563-a534-957d76ac98b9'
```